# Trying to get data from multiple web pages into excel

Tags: excel, vba, web

I am trying to pull a specific string of text from the following web page:

http://comptroller.texas.gov/taxinfo/salestax/collections1504.html

The 1504 represents year year month month and I want to decrease this number until 0504 (April 2005: http://comptroller.texas.gov/taxinfo/salestax/collections0504.html).

Rather than having to go through and copy/paste this string 120 times, I was wondering how to input this into VBA and have the code do this for me.

If you visit any of the links between 1504 and 0504, the string I am looking for is immediately following the first "$" and goes until the $ ends (9 characters).

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code I found with some research:

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
Dim Erw, firstRow, lastRow
firstRow = 1
Last Row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Erw = firstRow To lastRow
    Dim newRow
    newRow = firstRow + 4
    Range("B" & newRow).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("B" & newRow)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1", _
        Destination:=Range("$D$5"))
        .Name = "collections1504_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    nextRow = nextRow + 1
    Next Erw
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C5").Select
    Range("D3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D5:P143").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.QueryTable.Delete
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: And where does Excel come into the picture?

Comment: I added the code above. @Bond, I am trying to import this data into excel and then perform further analysis on it.

Comment: So... the data can go anywhere or...? The first $ is _"$2,297.7 million in April..."_. 9 characters would be "2,297.7 m". That's what you want?

Comment: I would like the data in the next column to the right. I suppose if you were to exclude the $ sign, it would be 7.

Comment: I have also edited the code to what it is now currently at.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of Query Tables, they've never worked that well for me.

The following code uses an instance `InternetExplorer` to navigate to the page and extract the string. It requires a couple of extra references to work, or modification to use CreateObject instead.

Adding the references adds the objects to IntelliType so its easier to edit the code.

You can use this function in a worksheet, multiple calls might make the worksheet freeze for a bit but I imagine that would happen with QueryTables too.

```
' This function requires references "Microsoft Internet Controls" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library"
Public Function getTax(ByVal DateCode As String) As String
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim Content As String
Dim Response As String
Dim Address As String
Dim Count As Integer: Count = 0

Address = "http://comptroller.texas.gov/taxinfo/salestax/collections" & DateCode & ".html"

Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
Browser.Navigate Address

Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set Document = Browser.Document

Do
    Set Element = Document.getElementById("fullPage")

    If Not Element Is Nothing Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        If Count > 5 Then
            Debug.Print "Error: getTax failed to find element."
            Exit Do
        Else
            ' Document might not be ready, give it a second. and try again
            Count = Count + 1
            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
        End If
    End If        
Loop

If Element Is Nothing Then
    Response = "[ERROR]"
Else
    Content = Element.innerText
    Response = Mid(Content, InStr(1, Content, "$") + 1, 7)
End If

Set Document = Nothing
Set Element = Nothing
Set Browser = Nothing

getTax = Response

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would rather directly scan the web page content. My method puts all the results on the spreadsheet in a chartable form. Here's another way to accomplish what you're looking for:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetSalesTaxData()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim taxMonth As Date
    Dim url As String
    Dim urlLeader As String
    Dim prefix As String
    Dim pos1 As Integer
    Dim pos2 As Integer
    Dim taxStr As String
    Dim dest As Range
    Dim rowOffset As Integer

    taxMonth = DateValue("4/1/2015")
    urlLeader = "http://comptroller.texas.gov/taxinfo/salestax/collections"
    prefix = "deposited to general revenue totaled"
    Set dest = Range("A1")
    rowOffset = 0

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False

    Do While taxMonth > DateValue("3/1/2005")
        url = urlLeader & Right(year(taxMonth), 2) & Format(Int(month(taxMonth)), "00") & ".html"
        ie.Navigate url
        Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        pos1 = InStr(1, ie.Document.body.innerhtml, prefix, vbTextCompare) + Len(prefix) + 1
        pos2 = InStr(pos1, ie.Document.body.innerhtml, "million", vbTextCompare)
        taxStr = Mid(ie.Document.body.innerhtml, pos1, (pos2 - pos1 - 1))
        '--- basic string clean up: strip the leading '$' and the comma
        taxStr = Replace(taxStr, "$", "", , , vbTextCompare)
        taxStr = Replace(taxStr, ",", "", , , vbTextCompare)
        '    on one of the answers there is a trailing '.' for some reason
        If Right(taxStr, 1) = "." Then
            taxStr = Left(taxStr, Len(taxStr) - 1)
        End If
        '--- store it in the worksheet
        dest.Cells(1 + rowOffset, 1).Value = taxMonth
        dest.Cells(1 + rowOffset, 2).Value = CDbl(taxStr)
        rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
        ' decrement the date by one month
        taxMonth = DateAdd("m", -1, taxMonth)
    Loop

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and it would not compile due to a "user-defined type not defined"

Comment: Sorry, you have to add a library reference to the Microsoft internet library. That will fix it.